# State in spring service

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

My code is as below . Here i use a local variable to store data and return it to the controller method. Whenever the scheduled post construct method runs i use a temporary list. But i read somewhere that spring service should not be having state. What is a better way to do this?

```
@Service
public class AppService
{
    private List<String> responseList = new ArrayList<>();

    @PostConstruct
    @Scheduled(every 2hours)
    public void getData()
    {
        //get data from another third party REST API endpoint and populate a temporary list

        //Once all data is fetched set temp list as mainList
        this.responseList = tempList;
    }

    public List<String> getResponse()
    {
        return this.responseList;
    }
}
```

Comment: "*i read somewhere that spring service should not be having state*" How can we refute a source if you don't provide it? Ignore this *somewhere*, it's fine.

Comment: Spring singleton-scope components should not have *conversational* state.  that means state specific to an individual client (which would result in different threads stepping on each other and overwriting data). That seems not to be the case here. It seems possible there could be visibility issues depending on how you do this. If you are using this to implement a cache you should probably check out cache managers instead.

Comment: Thanks Nathan and Michael i will check out caching. I am just starting out on spring boot and also posting my first question . so pardon me for those inaccurate questions

Answer (score 2):

Shahul,

It depends on two factors: (a) how the service is going to be used (i.e. deployed and operated) and (b) where is the data for the `responseList` is going to come from.

First, as @Michael said, you should always cite your sources. On Stackoverflow, it can help people see if you read wrong or outdated information or simply misunderstood the source and, eventually, help you more effectively. Indeed, https://spring.io/microservices states (emph. mine):

> The small, *stateless* nature of *microservices* makes them ideal for
>   horizontal scaling.

So here is the key to the first factor: if you want to make a microservice and scale it, it better be stateless. However, `@Service` in Spring defines a *Service Component* and it's [javadocs](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/stereotype/Service.html) state:

> Indicates that an annotated class is a "Service", originally defined by Domain-Driven Design (Evans, 2003) as "an operation offered as an interface that stands alone in the model, with no encapsulated state."

If you study the javadocs for other `@Component` descendants, you will see that `@Repository` has the following description:

> Indicates that an annotated class is a "Repository", originally defined by Domain-Driven Design (Evans, 2003) as "a mechanism for **encapsulating storage**, retrieval, and search behavior which emulates a collection of objects".

I recommend you read more about Repositories and Spring Persistence in general. The answer for factor B will tell you what kind of persistence method to use.

Comment: I edited and updated my question and i am not using a database to retrieve data. So does this mean i can use a local instance variable in Service class in such cases whether its a microservice or not.?

Comment: First, Repositories can be programmed to read and write from/to a text file, there is no hard requirement on using databases, they can even be in-memory. As @NathanHughes said, you can have some state. But I think for your purpose it would be best to define a rather simple Repository. I would then have this service save some entities in the repository and then other code can get the most recent ones from the same repository.

Comment: thank you berezovskyi. i will take the approach what you mentioned.